# Problems with god

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-1.9.3, god

So I have problems starting [god](http://godrb.com/) reliably. I might need to restart multiple times before everything succeeds.

```
OSX 10.6.8
Ruby 1.9.3-p236
god 0.13.2
```

I have a configuration file where I specify monitoring of two processes like this:

```
bindir = "/Users/me/foobar"
basedir = "/Users/me/foobar"

God::Contacts::Email.defaults do |d|
  d.from_email = 'god@example.copm'
  d.from_name = 'God'
  d.delivery_method = :sendmail
end

God.contact(:email) do |c|
  c.name = 'me'
  c.group = 'foobar'
  c.to_email = 'me@example.com'
end

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "foo"
  w.group = "foobar"
  w.dir = basedir
  w.log = "logs/foo.log"
  w.start = "ruby #{bindir}/foo.rb"
  w.keepalive

  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_exits) do |c|
      c.notify = 'me'
    end
  end
end

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "bar"
  w.group = "foobar"
  w.dir = basedir
  w.log = "logs/bar.log"
  w.start = "ruby #{bindir}/bar.rb"
  w.keepalive

  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_exits) do |c|
      c.notify = 'me'
    end
  end
end
```

If I start god with -D so I see it in the console it always works fine and my processes start.

```
god -c foobar.god -D
```

All good. Then I can also run stuff like:

```
god status
god stop foobar
god start foobar
god terminate foobar
```

All works.

Now if I start without the -D option it either (a) works as it should, (b) god starts the processes but itself not (or dies), or (c) nothing starts at all.

I have been looking for some kind of log entry but failed to find anything that would indicate that there is a failure. Also as I already described, it does work from time to time. Just not every time.

The other problem I have seen (that I don't know if it's related somehow at the moment) is that when god and my processes all run fine (without -D) it is most of the time not possible to successfully send commands to it. I.e. something like

```
god stop foobar
```

would just not terminate and just results in lots of dots

```
god terminate foobar
..............................................
```

and meanwhile I can see in top that god starts to take lots of CPU.

I have to hit ctrl-c and then kill the god process with -9 and then manually clean up the monitored processes.

I haven't found anything online that is even close to what I have described. I would very much like to find out what's going on. Can anyone help or do you have suggestions what I can try?

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE:

Killing the god process results in this stack trace:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:570:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:632:in `recv_reply'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:918:in `recv_reply'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1197:in `send_message'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1088:in `block (2 levels) in method_missing'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1172:in `open'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1087:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1105:in `with_friend'
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1086:in `method_missing'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/god-0.13.2/lib/god/cli/command.rb:183:in `terminate_command'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/god-0.13.2/lib/god/cli/command.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/god-0.13.2/lib/god/cli/command.rb:10:in `initialize'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/god-0.13.2/bin/god:121:in `new'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/god-0.13.2/bin/god:121:in `'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/god:19:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/god:19:in `'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
```

Searching online caught [this bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7833) in Ruby.